# How to get the dirty data from a QSqlTableModel with OnManualSubmit

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a database with values and a QSqlTableModel on top of that.

I subclassed the model (based on the idea in the [qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_a_QSqlQueryModel_in_QML#A_more_generic_approach) and mostly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399340)) so that I can define custom roles that enable me to use the following QML table view in the `.ui.qml`:

```
TableView {
   TableViewColumn {
     id: nameColumn
     role: "name"
     title: qsTr("Name")
   }
   TableViewColumn {
      id: textColumn
      role: "specialText"
      title: qsTr("Text")
   }
   TableViewColumn {
      id: descriptionColumn
      role: "description"
      title: qsTr("Description")
    }

    model: SpecialSqlModel
}
```

along with the code in the `.qml` (actually for all three columns)

```
Component {
  id: nameDelegate
  TextInput {
    onEditingFinished: {
      console.log(styleData.row + ", name: " + text);
      SoecialSqlModel.setData( styleData.row, text, 1);
    }
    text: styleData.value
  }
}


nameColumn.delegate: nameDelegate
```

I set the model in the `.cpp` file as

```
 auto mView = new QQuickWidget(this);
 auto mDb = QSqlDatabase::database("localdb");
 auto mModel = new DbTableModel(mView, mDb);

 mModel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
 mModel->setTable("Table");
 mModel->select()

 mView->rootContext()->setContextProperty("SpecialSqlModel", mModel);
```

That works a expected in the sense that I can edit the fields in the qml. Since my strategy is `QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit`, the model is dirty until I `submitAll()` manually. In that case, the data is updated and reflected in the view.

However, I want to submit when the user clicks ready and I want the view to show the pending changes until the user does so. The problem is that, when calling the `QSqlQueryModel::data` function, I get the old data, not the new cached one.

How can I get the view to show the cached data instead of the submitted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

In my subclass, I wanted to use a proxy to `QSqlTableModel::data` but instead wrote `QSqlQueryModel::data` which queried the database and did not use the cached data.